# How to remove space between the jquery mobile grid?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am using multiple jQuery Mobile grids in the page and I want to remove the space between the grid.

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" data-corners="false" data-icon="alert" data-iconpos="top" data-role="button" onclick="click()">Button 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="#" data-corners="false" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="top" data-role="button" onclick="click()">button 2 </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" data-corners="false" data-icon="location" data-iconpos="top" data-role="button" onclick="click()">Button 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="#" data-corners="false" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="top" data-role="button" onclick="click()">button 4 </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Check this demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wtkmw69/)

It shows spaces between the buttons, but I need that button to cover all the space.
I only want changes for this grid, as there are multiple grids on the page.

Comment: r u looking like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/9wtkmw69/3/

Comment: ya i m looking for the same.thx :)
but just one question if i write that custom css so it will override the default jqm css and all the grid will show result like this.?

Comment: use your parent selector `.ui-grid-a` in the css. So that it will affect only this div.

Comment: i have updated my fiddle and post it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, Update your CSS like below and target based on the parent class.

```
 .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>.ui-btn, .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>.ui-select,  .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>.ui-checkbox,  .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>.ui-radio,  .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>button.ui-btn-inline,  .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>button.ui-btn-icon-notext
{
margin:0px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9wtkmw69/5/)

Comment: thx for the fast answer @suresh. but applying that effect applies on all the grid on the page.

i just want to make particular grid should take effect. 

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/9wtkmw69/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got to solution as i wanted with help of @Suresh's answer.

```
.no-margin-grid .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>.ui-btn, .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>.ui-select,  .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>.ui-checkbox,  .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>.ui-radio,  .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>button.ui-btn-inline,  .ui-grid-a [class*=ui-block-]>button.ui-btn-icon-notext
{
margin:0px;
}
```

just adding .no-margin-grid custom class to css and defining extra div.

```
<div class="no-margin-grid">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" data-corners="false" data-icon="alert" data-iconpos="top" data-          role="button" onclick="click()">Button 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="#" data-corners="false" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="top" data-role="button" onclick="click()">button 2 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" data-corners="false" data-icon="location" data-iconpos="top" data-role="button" onclick="click()">Button 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="#" data-corners="false" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="top" data-role="button" onclick="click()">button 4 </a>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9wtkmw69/7/)**